# Unsharp window with phonegap and Jquery/html canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to make my first app but it seems as if the whole screen is always out of focus. The resolution is (on the Iphone 6+) 1080x1920. When I create an object with the size $(window).innerWidth x $(window).innerHeight, the object end up being something like 320x568? I have some standard meta tags which are probably not working.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: try to remove these: `width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"` this also: `user-scalable=no`

Comment: @odedta Not working. EDIT: that link describes my issue, but there is no solution

Comment: You have to understand that the `meta` says is how to render the webpage on your device's screen. So, just start with the basic meta tag to allow for mobile responsiveness `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` and work your way from there. Did you check this: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: I tried working my way with the meta tags but it seems that absolutely no viewport tag is working? Maybe an issue with phonegap?

Comment: Probably not, can you provide with a jsfiddle perhaps? is your code valid (http://validator.w3.org/)? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: I might have misconfigured the config.xml file perhaps? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pezyf0sd/1/) all the code I run. I am new to phonegap, so I think it might be a misconfig.

Comment: I also uploaded my config file [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnhvdk4y/)

Comment: It seems that when I remove the line `document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {` from your Javascript the canvas changes size. http://jsfiddle.net/pezyf0sd/2/

Comment: Yes it does, but that line needs to stay since it is required by phonegap, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not familiar with Cordova but as it looks in their docs you stated that event listener wrong... look: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html
should be like: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}` look for "Quick Example"

Comment: Tried this, same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. You are using `window.innerWidth`, which always returns CSS pixels (also known as device-independent pixels). On iPhone 3,4,5 it'll return `320px`, on iPhone 6 and 6+ it'll return `375px` and `414px` respectively. Unless the iPhone users have enabled the accessibility feature called `Display Zoom`. Then it'll be `320px` and `375px` for iPhone 6 and 6+ respectively.

You should use the above dimensions for rendering any HTML and using CSS. E.g. you want a `full-screen-wide DIV`? Set `width` to `320px` (of course, you can also set it to `100%`).

But if you are rendering images (including Canvas), you should supply them at native device resolution. If you want a non-blurry `full-screen-wide IMG`, set `width` to `100%` or `320px` but point `SRC` to an **at least** `640px`-wide image on iPhone 4&5. A full-width non-blurry image on iPhone 6+ has to be at least 414*3 = `1242px`.

But here's the bad news. Your 1242px image will be taken at face value and then downscaled by 1.15 to 1080px, making it not pixel perfect. Supplying a 1080px image will not help, because it will be up-scaled to 1242px and then down to 1080px during different render phases in the OS / browser engine. The good news is that it won't matter either way at those ginormous resolutions. You won't be able to see it.

So if you're rendering a full-width `canvas`, don't use CSS pixel count from `innerWidth`. Use native pixel count by multiplying `window.innerWidth` with `window.devicePixelRatio`. It returns '2' on my MBPr and iPhone 6 and `3` on iPhone 6+.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still get the same issue, but now the canvas reaches out of the window. The scaling issue must be somewhere in the HTML or maybe in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. Set the canvas to width/height 100% in the css file.
2. Add this snippet in your js file:

   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID');
   canvas.width = $(window).innerWidth() * window.devicePixelRatio;
   canvas.height = $(window).innerHeight() * window.devicePixelRatio;